# zip install したら「python setup.py egg_info は正常に実行されませんでした。」と出てどうすれば抜けれるのか。

Tags: python, docker

Docker, Python によるアプリ開発を行っています。

`pip install zip` を実行すると以下のようなメッセージが表示されました。
どうやったらエラーを抜け出せれるか知りたいです。

参考にしたサイト

- [意外と簡単！！Pythonで作るAndroidアプリ【Python】(Buildozer)  (YouTube)](https://youtube.com/watch?v=DB7_YoJNNeg)
- [Kivyで作成したPythonアプリケーションをAndroidパッケージ化する](https://qiita.com/t2hk/items/3b1b18d51db6274fd864)

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-j_b38oqn/wsgiref_2ba90b298ac5464ea3ae97c382c62372/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
          import ez_setup
        File "/tmp/pip-install-j_b38oqn/wsgiref_2ba90b298ac5464ea3ae97c382c62372/ez_setup/__init__.py", line 170
          print "Setuptools version",version,"or greater has been installed."
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
root@2b01a330cdbf:/#
```

Comment: そもそも [zip - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/zip/) ってDockerでのPythonアプリ開発環境に必要なのでしょうか？ 何か別のモジュール名が不足していたりしませんか？ 参考にしている記事とか書いておくと助言・回答が付きやすいでしょう。[【2022年版】VSCode + Dockerで最強のPython開発環境を構築する【Remote Development】](https://www.true-fly.com/entry/2021/12/08/073000), [【5分で出来る】Dockerを使ってPython環境を構築してみよう！](https://toukei-lab.com/docker_python), [Dockerを使ってPythonの開発環境を用意してみる](https://atsblog.org/docker-python/), [Docker上でPython開発環境を構築する](https://shikaku-mafia.com/docker-python-dev-env/)

Comment: 参考にしているサイトです。説明がうまくできなくて申し訳ございません。；YouTube：https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DB7_YoJNNeg&feature=emb_imp_woyt　　　qiita:https://qiita.com/t2hk/items/3b1b18d51db6274fd864

Comment: コメントではなく質問記事の方を編集して追記しましょう。ビデオの方は見ていませんがテキストの記事には`pip install zip`といった記述は無いのですが、出来上がった後で独自に何かのインストールをしようとしているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

インストールしようとしている`zip`というモジュール名とエラーメッセージの`SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?`から考えると、対象は[zip - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/zip/)でリポジトリはこちら[kdheepak/zip](https://github.com/kdheepak/zip)だと思われますが、参考にしているビデオや記事は`kivy`によるモバイルアプリケーションの開発なのに、インストールしようとしているのは`flask`や`react`のためのモジュールであるらしいのは、何か整合性が取れていないのでは？

エラーメッセージの`SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?`と[kdheepak/zip](https://github.com/kdheepak/zip)にある`.travis.yaml`, `runtime.txt`の記述が`python 2.7`用で、`tox.ini`の記述が`envlist = py26, py27, py33, py34, py35`であることを考えると、Python 3.x系のdockerにPython2.7のためのモジュールをインストールしようとして発生した問題と考えられます。

そうした必要とするPython版数を合わせることと、`zip`リポジトリの中にある`requirements.txt`の内容が主に`flask`であることとか、`packages.json`の内容が主に`babel`, `react`であることから、参考にした`kivy`アプリケーションのためのdocker環境構築の記事と`flask`, `react`のためのモジュールを組み合わせても問題無いのかどうかを確認した方が良いと思われます。

---

考え方としては以下3つくらいでしょうか。

- やりたい事は`kivy`アプリケーション開発であって、`zip`はたまたま試しただけ
  →`zip`はインストールしない
- `zip`を使うのが主目的
  →Python 2.7でDockerを作る記事や解説を探す
- `flask`や`react`を使える環境が欲しいが`zip`でなくても良い
  →`zip`はインストールせず、Python3.x系での`flask`や`react`を使える環境構築の記事や解説を探す。`kivy`アプリケーション開発環境と組み合わせて問題無いかも調べておく。